# Conjectured Form of $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2r}\left(r+1\right)^{x}}{r!}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Conjecture:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2r}\left(r+1\right)^{x}}{r!}\right)\overset{?}{=}{}\frac{\Gamma\left(x+2\right)}{\pi x^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x^{2}\cos\left(\sin t\right)e^{\cos t}}\cos\left(x^{2}e^{\cos t}\sin\left(\sin t\right)-\left(x+1\right)t\right)dt$$

I am not able to confirm this numerically.
Could anyone help.

Let,
$$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x^{2}\cos\left(\sin t\right)e^{\cos t}}\cos\left(x^{2}e^{\cos t}\sin\left(\sin t\right)-\left(x+1\right)t\right)dt$$
$$\frac{I(n)(n+1)!}{\pi n^2e^{n^2}} \in \text{N}\ \forall \ n\in \text{N}$$
The Integral can be broken down as follows:
$$I(x)=I_1(x)+I_2(x)$$
$$I_1(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x^{2}\cos\left(\sin t\right)e^{\cos t}}\cos\left(x^{2}\sin\left(\sin t\right)e^{\cos t}\right)\cos\left(\left(x+1\right)t\right)dt$$
$$I_2(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x^{2}\cos\left(\sin t\right)e^{\cos t}}\sin\left(x^{2}\sin\left(\sin t\right)e^{\cos t}\right)\sin\left(\left(x+1\right)t\right)dt$$

For small values $I_1(x)=I_2(x)$, I am not able to confirm the equality.

The Integral can be broken down more after expanding the Trigonometric Terms.

This is based on my previous question asked here. [Summation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2n}\left(n+1\right)^{x}\ }{n!}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754706/summation-sum-n-0-infty-left-fracx2n-leftn1-rightx-n-righ)

If anyone could numerically verify whether the conjecture is true or not.

And is it possible to evaluate the Integral further?

Answer (score 1):

Two interesting problems in a couple of days.

Numerically, the integrals make a lot of problems as soon as $x>4$.

Taking into account your previous remarks, what I computed is
$$J_1(x)=e^{-x^2}\,I_1(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad J_2(x)=e^{-x^2}\,I_2(x)$$

There is something which is interesting : for a `WorkingPrecision=500`

$$J_1(1)=J_2(1)=\frac \pi 2$$ which already seems to invalidate the conjecture.

Using `WorkingPrecision=50` and truncating
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & J_1(x) & J_2(x) \\
 1 & 1.5707963267948966192 & 1.5707963267948966192 \\
 2 & 30.368728984701334638 & 30.368728984701334638 \\
 3 & 753.39318823900229100 & 753.39318823900229100 \\
 4 & 23695.357869945895841 & 23695.357869945895841 \\
 5 & 910715.58530913653920 & 910715.58530913653920 \\
 6 & 41496402.422500335020 & 41496402.422500335020 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ which do not look like the sequence
$$\{2,29,1279,113137,16697651,3698440237\}$$

Comment: I think I have another form for the sequence:
$$\left[\frac{\text{d}^{n+1}}{\text{d}x^{n+1}}e^{n^2e^x}\right]_{x=0}\frac{1}{n^2e^{n^2}}$$
All of this seems related to Touchard Polynomials, but I am still in school and these seem out of my scope.
Also thank you for the numerical evaluation, I will check up on that Integral again. My original question was to find the closed form of the function, but it seems to be difficult.

Comment: $$I(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{n^{2}e^{\cos t}\cos\left(\sin t\right)}\cos\left(n^{2}e^{\cos t}\sin\left(\sin t\right)-\left(n+1\right)t\right)dt$$
$$S_n=\frac{(n+1)!}{\pi n^2e^{n^2}}I(n)$$

It does seem to define the Sequence, but again I am using Desmos for numerical verification and it works for $n=1...3$, after that it cannot really compute clearly.

Comment: @BlackEmperor. Why don't you register for Wolfram Cloud ? It is free.

Comment: Oh! If it is free then I shall do so. Thanks.

Comment: What you wrote for $S_n$ is  strictely exact. The "small" problem is $I(n)$. Nice problem

Comment: Now that I searched the Integral on Approach0, it seems to be the Integral Representation of [Bell Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706720/integral-representation-of-bell-polynomial)